# dlopen works but dlsym doesn't

Tags: c++, c, linux

I'm loading a `so` library on Linux using the following snippet:

```
handle = dlopen("myLib.so", RTLD_LAZY);
if(handle == NULL) {
  throw std::runtime_error("unable to load myLib.so");
}
```

Further down I then try to access a method in the `so`:

```
getter = dlsym(handle, "getMethod");
if(getter == 0) {
  std::ostringstream msg;
  msg << "missing entry point " << dlerror();
  throw std::runtime_error(msg.str().c_str());
}
```

When running this, there is no exception at the `dlopen` stage, but I keep getting the error:

`missing entry point undefined symbol: getMethod`

Running `nm` on `myLib.so` shows the `getMethod`:

```
> nm myLib.so | grep get

0000000000024220 T getMethod
```

I want and I'm also using `extern "C"` on that method as well.

**UPDATE**

I'm suspecting now that although the NULL check of the handle doesn't cause an exception, there may be an issue with the handle itself.

Is there anyway I can perform any further checks on the handle other than just == NULL, to confirm the call the dlopen was successful?

Comment: Does it show a `T` or `t` in `nm`? If it shows a `t` it indicates that the function is not exported. Are there leading underscores in the method name? You should also display the `nm` output in your question as well.

Comment: Added to original post (it shows `T`)

Comment: Would it be possible to provide some information about how you created the .so file?

Comment: Library created using cmake `ADD_LIBRARY, and 'SHARED'`

Comment: It sounds like it should be really easy to come up with an SSCCE (http://sscce.org/) for both the shared object and the main program. Could you do that and post the code (along with the build commands you're using)?

Comment: Are you *absolutely positive* that the handle being used in `dlsym` is the same value as returned from `dlopen`. If it got set back to `0`, then you would see what you're seeing; if it got set to some random value, then you generally get a `SEGV`

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that there are some failed dependencies, and `RTLD_LAZY` is masking that. Try using `RTLD_NOW` instead to see if you can still `dlopen()` the shared object.

Comment: Would you imagine that `ldd` would also show dependency issues if that was the case?

Comment: @imrichardcole: I should think so.